# Can someone help me figure out how to grab the appropriate data from this client side API GET request?

Tags: javascript, get, client, fetch-api

I am trying to make a GET request to this API endpoint "https://covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com/v1/usa"

Documentation is here: https://rapidapi.com/slotixsro-slotixsro-default/api/covid-19-tracking?endpoint=apiendpoint_7d5ee8f3-b6ad-49db-a824-baaad42d87c0)

My fetch request is below:

```
fetch("https://covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com/v1/usa", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-key": "...",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com",
                "content-type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });
```

As you can see it is basically exactly how it is in the example code snippet in the API documentation. But my response has no actual usable data in it, as seen below. Is my fetch request set up wrong or is there something I am missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the description at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```js
fetch("https://covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com/v1/usa", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "...",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "covid-19-tracking.p.rapidapi.com",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: Wow that worked @mplungjan, thank you! I have a question, so I had the following

.then(response => {response.json()})
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

If you compare with yours, the only difference is I have {} around response.json(), but that seems to cause data to be undefined, can you explain why that is?

Comment: You had missed `.then(response => response.json())` completely and thus you console.log'ed the response object instead of the JSON part